# Let $ba=a^4b^3$, show that $\mathrm{ord}(a^4b)=\mathrm{ord}(a^2b^3)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Let $ba=a^4b^3$ show that $\mathrm{ord}(a^4b)=\mathrm{ord}(a^2b^3)$ where $a,b\in G$ and $G$ is a group.

I have toiled on this problem for the past 2.5 hours. I tried substitution of the elements with their expressions. I tried taking advantage of conjugation. I also tried showing commutativity of $a$ and $b$. I don't know what I am not seeing. I hope the trick is satisfying I guess since I can't figure it out.

I would appreciate any hints. I prefer hints to complete solutions. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You should first be able to show that, for any $x,y\in G$, $\operatorname{ord}(xy)=\operatorname{ord}(yx)$. Now, see if this is helpful along with
$$bab^{-2}=a^4b,\ a^{-2}ba=a^2b^3.$$

Comment: Oh wait. Thank you

Comment: Amazing. You just made me realized that all the things that I wished for (like commutativity) were there all along in $\mathrm{ord}$ context. Thank you!

Comment: @crystal_math You're welcome! One thing to note is that you can't necessarily rearrange **all** terms inside $\operatorname{ord}$; the fact that $\operatorname{ord}(xy)=\operatorname{ord}(yx)$ can't be used to get that, for example, $\operatorname{ord}(xyz)=\operatorname{ord}(yxz)$, so you do have to be a _little_ bit careful.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I can cycle through them but in this case it is reduces to commutativity